# help me automate this process

Tags: boot, automation, process, windows-server-2003

I come from a unix background, and need to do this on Windows Server 2003.

Basically I have a command line process that I start from the windows `cmd.exe`. I want to achieve the following:

1. Make this process start on Windows boot by default, without having a user need to log in to start it.
2. Have a desktop icon that can restart this background process (in case it crashes). So something like a '`nohup mycommand &`' on *nix

Comment: Is this a domain connected pc?

Comment: @kronos, i log on via remote desktop via my mac book pro

Comment: I was thinking that this would be better over at ServerFault, but since you don't know what it is... then there's no need :)

Comment: @kronos, lol should be applicable here too though right?

Comment: Yes you are good

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Running at boot

Turn your process into a Windows Service using the [sc command](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/251192).  Basic syntax:

```
sc create NewServiceName binpath= c:\windows\system32\newserv.exe
```

Note the space after `binpath=`.  Once you create the service you can configure it to run automatically like any other service.  If you're unclear on that, go to the start menu and choose `Run`.  Enter `services.msc` into the window that opens.  This will open the services snap-in in the Microsoft Management Console.  From here you should be able to find your service listed (among many others) and set it to run automatically using the gui tools.  You could also make this part of your `sc create` command, but for a novice it's likely much easier to just get the darn thing created and then use the gui tools to set it up the way you want.

One final caveat is to make sure you run this with an account that has the appropriate permissions.  The Service or System accounts are best, but sometimes you need something different.

#### Restarting on demand

A little batch (*.bat) file will do the trick:

```
sc stop NewServiceName
sc start NewServiceName
```

Comment: Nice explanation!

Comment: @joel will try this thanx

Comment: @joel - finally getting around to this.  what if the command i use from the command line is 'java -jar thewar.war'?  would that go in the binpath with the quotes?

Comment: I think you'd have to wrap the command in a .bat file and use the .bat file as the binpath

Comment: @joel, is that just a file with .bat on the end with the one line?

Comment: Yes, that's all it is. Welcome to the <strike>wonderful</strike>mediocre world of windows shell scripting.  Actually, I kid.  For the _really_ simple stuff, .bat is awesome.  For the _really_ hard stuff, powershell is more than up to the task.  It's the in-between stuff that can get you.

Comment: @joel, ok i created the service with the sc command and the .bat file, however from the services gui i cannot start it.  i get error 1053, the service did not respond to the start on control request in a timely fashion -- when i run the .bat file with the exact same binpath i used to create the service a new terminal opens and the thing starts

Comment: hmm..  looking again, I'd create the service for the basic java vm software.  After creating the service, there's a place in the services snap-in configuration for each service that you can use to enter start parameters.

Comment: @joel,  this is a command line java app.  I dont think it should work like that.  Is there anything else it could be?  you have been very helpful, should i start a new question on this specific question?

Answer (score 0):

Make a service out of your process that runs under Local System. Then, make a batch script on the desktop to start and stop the service.

EDIT:

Here's some links:
[Running a program as a service](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/137890)
[Managing services from the command-line](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc736564(WS.10).aspx#BKMK_cmd)
[Making a batch script](http://commandwindows.com/batch.htm)

Comment: I don't think the OP knows what you mean, considering he's actually a *nix guy. Can you explain how to accomplish that?

Comment: I don't think the downvote was necessary. The answer's not wrong. I figured he could Google it and get more comprehensive information that I could provide in this answer. I will add links in the edit...

Comment: The point of Super User (for the most part) is to present a solution that is complete... not always a hint that someone still has to do research in...

Comment: Simply linking just adds link rot to the site. Read Joels answer that is a proper well written answer: he used links but only as sources after quoting said sources.

Comment: @Kronos @Kyle Amen.

Comment: I still don't think it was downvote-worthy.  If the original answer here (before the links were added) were the only answer to the question, it still added enough new knowledge (try for a Windows Service) to probably allow the OP to solve his problem with a little more research.

Comment: I am going to disagree on Kyle's point on what constitutes a good answer. I'm giving OP the information necessary to learn the concept instead of typing in some commands and then having to come back next time it screws up or whatnot. As well, my answer provides the information necessary to others to answer similar questions, or questions that need more depth (eg. dependencies). What it boils down to was the OP's question was so vague, it necessitated a vague answer.

Answer (score 0):

On the 2003 Server, open a Local computer Policy snapin in MMC.  Expand Computer Configuration-Windows Settings and then open Scripts (Startup/Shutdown) Open Startup and you can add your script there.  It should stored be in the sysvol share.

You can also create a shortcut to this script on the desktop